# ManyRelatedManager not Iterable. Think I'm trying to pull my objects out incorrectly

Tags: django, django-views

I'm just trying to pull out each individual event from a list of events and perform an action on them. The code I currently have in my view is:

```
    user = request.user.get_profile()
    followed = user.eventList
    eL = [getEvent.getEvent(e_id) for e_id in followed]
```

First, I'm grabbing the currently logged in user, then looking at his eventList, then iterating over it. I get the above error. Think I may be missing some line?

Comment: TypeError at /
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable. Happens at the third line

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Assuming from the error that `eventList` is a many-to-many field, you need to use `.all()` to get the related objects.  A many-to-many field is a manager, so you can use it to construct querysets that return the actual objects.

```
user = request.user.get_profile()
eL = user.eventList.all()
```

Comment: Thanks so much I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: it seems like prefetch_related might help you out a bit, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related